# Having trouble getting html2haml to work using stdin

Tags: console, haml, html2haml

I might just be thick this morning but I cannot seem to get `html2haml` with the `-s` or `--stdin` option to work.

Running `html2haml` or `html2haml -s` on the command line looks like I get put into some input mode but with no way to escape but `^c`. This causes an interrupt and nothing more happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to send end of file so `html2haml` knows the input is finished, rather than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> which interrupts the process. (These keys are actually the defaults and may vary, but are probably right for you).